# Calculating Aggregates on subset of data based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB as follows:

```
| company | timestamp  | value |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- |
| google  | 2020-09-01 | 5     |
| google  | 2020-08-01 | 4     |
| amazon  | 2020-09-02 | 3     |
```

I'd like to calculate the average `value` for each company within the last year if there are >= 20 datapoints. If there are less than 20 datapoints then I'd like the average during the entire time duration. I know I can do two separate queries and get the averages for each scenario. The question I suppose is how do I merge them back in a single table based on the criteria I have.

```
select company, avg(value) from my_db GROUP BY company;

select company, avg(value) from my_db
where timestamp > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months')
GROUP BY company;
```

Comment: *if there are >= 20 datapoints* do you mean the total sum of value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH last_year AS (
   SELECT company, avg(value), 'year' AS range  -- optional tag
   FROM   tbl      
   WHERE  timestamp >= now() - interval '1 year'
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) >= 20  -- 20+ rows in range
   )
SELECT company, avg(value), 'all' AS range
FROM   tbl
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM last_year WHERE company = t.company)
GROUP  BY 1
UNION ALL TABLE last_year;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8acf0177e78dabd644af870f26c19180)*

An index on `(timestamp)` will only be used if your table is big and holds many years.

If most companies have 20+ rows in range, an index on `(company)` will be used for the 2nd `SELECT` to retrieve the few outliers.

Comment: Lots of great answers on here but this seemed to be the clearest syntax.

Comment: @Zaheer I'm surprised that you see the *clearest syntax* in a query that aggregates twice in the table and also uses UNION ALL for the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select company, 
       case 
         when sum(case when timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months' then value end) >= 20 then 
              avg(case when timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months' then value end)
         else avg(value)
       end
from my_db 
group by company
```

If by 20 datapoints you mean 20 rows in the last 12 months for each company, then:

```
select company, 
       case 
         when count(case when timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months' then value end) >= 20 then 
              avg(case when timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months' then value end)
         else avg(value)
       end
from my_db 
group by company
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to provide the information for filtering:

```
select company, avg(value),
       (count(*) = cnt_this_year) as only_this_year
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where date_trunc('year', datecol) = date_trunc('year', now()) over (partition by company) as cnt_this_year
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_this_year >= 20 and date_trunc('year', datecol) = date_trunc('year', now()) or
      cnt_this_year < 20
group by company;
```

The third column specifies if all the rows are from this year.  By filtering in the `where` clause, it is simple to add other calculations as well (such as `min()`, `max()`, and so on).